# Realizar backup automatico MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

Estou utilizando o MySQL como SGBD, e ao pesquisar na internet uma forma de criar uma rotina de *backup* descobri que as versões antigas possuíam uma ferramenta que deixou de existir nas versões mais novas, acredito que quem usa o MySQL não ficou nas versões antigas.

Gostaria de saber se hoje existe uma forma correta de criar esta rotina de *backup* ou não cada um faz de uma forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"MySQL Workbench é um cliente de consulta e ferramenta para modelagem e muito bom nisso - o objetivo não é para executar tarefas do servidor - que é o trabalho do servidor. Você pode executar backups manuais usando Workbench, mas eu estou supondo que não é seu objetivo a longo prazo.

Há muitas maneiras que você pode executar backups. Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://www.noupe.com/development/10-ways-to-automatically-manually-backup-mysql-database.html) para 10 deles. Algumas das soluções são dependente do SO basicamente, você tem mais opções se você estiver em Linux /*nix do que no Windows (qual é seu?). Além disso, ele depende que suas tabelas sejam InnoDB ou MyISAM (espero que seja InnoDB!).

Dois outros (Open Source) soluções de backup não mencionados no post acima são de [Percona XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) que pode ser cron'd ou [Zmanda 's](http://amanda.zmanda.com/) (que foi mencionado no [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) livro por Schwartz et al.). Outra solução seria [MyDumper](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2014/03/10/new-mydumper-0-6-1-release-offers-several-performance-and-usability-features/) - novamente uma ferramenta apoiada Percona (exceto este também lida com tabelas MyISAM).

Se você estiver familiarizado com os sistemas * nix e de arquivo, então talvez uma solução LVM pode ser boa para você? Experimente [aqui](http://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/) .

Aconselho-vos a estudar as soluções disponíveis e fazer alguns testes e ver qual deles atende melhor às suas necessidades."

*As vezes é preciso buscar um pouco mais! Abraço.
[Texto original](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74412/automatic-backup-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Eu utilizo Windows.

Comment: então vc pode tentar um desses programas, ou realizar manualmente `Server/Export` ou `Server/Back Up e Recovery` e criar uma configuração no `my.cnf`

Answer (score 0):

> Você pode usar [esse script em Python](https://gist.github.com/jniltinho/5565364) que eu criei, ele faz backup de todas as bases de Dados.

Baixe ele, execute um **chmod +x backup_mysql.py** e coloque na pasta **/usr/local/bin/**

Comment: Tem como você colocar os códigos aqui também? Desta forma vai que acontece algum problema e esse *link* deixe de existir, a resposta não fica inválida. Dá uma revisada em tudo o que postou.

Comment: Nilton, revisando algumas de suas publicações, reparei em várias com esse mesmo formato, e as converti para comentários. Se você editá-las para deixá-las mais completas, não esqueça de sinalizá-las para que um moderador possa avaliar e se for o caso restaurar as respostas. Obrigado

Comment: Tudo bem, colocar o código aqui do script fica muito grande e sempre eu atualizo esse script, é muito raro eu excluir meus próprios scripts pois eles fazem partem de vários projetos.